# Rational behind R's summary() functions calculations

Tags: r, summary

Does R's `summary()` function excludes `NA` values while calculating averages. Although I have  tried to find  information from help documentation, I wasn't able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does, look at this example:

```
x1 <- c(1, 4, 3, NA, 7)
summary(x1)
```

Output:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   1.00    2.50    3.50    3.75    4.75    7.00       1
```

Now look:

```
mean(x1)
> [1] NA
```

and:

```
mean(x1, na.rm=T)
[1] 3.75
```

So, summary indeed use na.rm=T for the statistics, and the last result is the NA's count (in my example NA's = 1).

The example was taken from: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/missing.htm

Answer (score 1):

The answer by ddsu shows it does, but here's how it does it. Check the `summary.default` source code. Starting on line 14:

```
else if (is.numeric(object)) {
    nas <- is.na(object)
    object <- object[!nas]
    qq <- stats::quantile(object)
    qq <- signif(c(qq[1L:3L], mean(object), qq[4L:5L]), digits)
    names(qq) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", 
                   "Max.")
    if (any(nas)) 
      c(qq, `NA's` = sum(nas))
    else qq
  }
```

So before calculating the values the NAs are filtered out and then their counted added if there's any.